# Electrical outlets not working

Tags: electrical

I replaced a few outlets in my home over the past weekend and now some other outlets (which I assume are downstream) are not working.  The outlet that I replaced still works fine but I cannot figure out why the others are not working.  I checked the circuit breaker and reset all the switches.  All of the wires in the outlets have been double checked to make sure there are no loose wires.

One of the outlets that I replaced (and assuming this is the problematic one) has a black wire, a res wire, 3 white wires, and a ground.  I screwed them all into the new outlet and no luck.  I tried bypassing the outlet all together by putting the red and black wire together and all the whites together but still no luck.

Any suggestions?  I have gotten a few quotes from electricians but they all want $300+ to come out and fix it.

Thanks in advance[image][image][image]

Comment: Was that outlet controlled by a switch?

Comment: No there is no switch connected to the outlet.

Comment: Is that 1 black 1 red and 3 whites?  That is strange did you place the wires in the same locations on the new outlet as the original?  The extra white has me puzzled, could you post a photo of the wires coming into the box.

Comment: I just added a pic.  Since that pic was taken, I have pigtails all of the whites together and didn't make a difference.

Comment: I did not place them exactly as they were on the old outlet as the old outlet had 8 push connectors on the back.  Wish I would have taken a picture of it before but never ran into any issues like this when replacing other outlets.

Comment: You should not have 2 wires under one screw like that. Use a pigtail instead. Cut a 6 to 8 inch piece of white wire out of some extra cable, and strip both ends. Using a wirenut, connect this new pigtail wire to all three of the white wires. Then connect the other end of the pigtail to the outlet.

Comment: I can't tell whether the whites are just being used as a big 4-way splice (3 whites + receptacle itself) or whether they **neutral-split** the receptacle because they had also **hot-split** the receptacle on different circuits.  Only looking at the old receptacle, and looking at the "Tabs" found between the screws and whether they're broken off or not, will tell the  tale.  Ignoring the tabs has a 50/50 chance of making a big bang boom immediately, and if the neutral should be split and isn't, has a chance of burning your house down much later.

Answer (score 1):

Solved.  Must have been a faulty outlet which I guess is very uncommon.  Installed another new outlet and everything now works.  Thanks for everyone's help!!

Comment: Just because the receptacles now "work" doesn't mean they are correctly connected or they are safe. You should address the questions in the comments above.

Comment: Since the op said the new outlet was wired the same as the old and replacing the outlet it worked how are we to know it is not correct? I don't remember having a outlet that was bad with screw terminals and the extra white concerns me but if the op accepts the answer it will be done.

Comment: Please click the check mark next to your answer so others know this has been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

There is a second black wire that you left dangling (I guess). You can see it on the first picture, right side of the wall opening, mid-height. It seems to be a slightly glossier black (newer wire?). It probably needs to be pigtailed to the other black.

Comment: Unfortunately that is not another black wire.  Must be something strange with the picture.  I took another pic with the outlet off of the wall.  There is one white and one black going down the wall (assuming to the other outlets) and on the top there are 2 whites, a red, and 2 blacks that were tied together previously that I did not touch.  Everything was working before I switched out this outlet.  The 3 whites were all plugged into the old outlet along with the one red, one black, and the ground.   I really appreciate all the help!